# C++ RegEnumValue throws ERROR_MORE_DATA

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

Im trying to get all my comports  from the registry.
Unfortunately i always recieve the ERROR_MORE_DATA error...
I already tried to make my buffer bigger, but it wont help at all.
Here is my code:

```
DWORD registry::regGetValue(char *key, int index)
{
HKEY hKey; 
 RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM",0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&hKey);
     DWORD chars = sizeof(key);
     LONG result = RegEnumValue(hKey, index, key, &chars, 0,0,0,0 );
 RegCloseKey(hKey);
 return result;
}
```

Parameters are:

```
char key[512];
int index = 0;
```

Comment: sizeof(key) is 4 because it is a pointer. Pass the actual size of the buffer to your function and use that.

Comment: thanks a lot man, works perfectly.
The problem was that i always tried to get the size with sizeof(),
even when i wanted to get the size of a static number.
Solution is: DWORD chars = 512;

Answer (score 2):

The buffer is likely big enough, you're just lying to the function about its actual size.

When you use the `sizeof` operator on a pointer, it returns **the size of the pointer**, not the size of the array to which it points. And because `key` is passed to the function as a `char*`, it is merely a pointer to the array, not the array itself.

You have to pass the actual size of the buffer to your function as a parameter along with the pointer:

```
DWORD regGetValue(char *key, size_t length, int index)
{
   HKEY hKey; 
   RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM",0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&hKey);
   DWORD chars = length;
   LONG result = RegEnumValue(hKey, index, key, &chars, 0,0,0,0 );
   RegCloseKey(hKey);
   return result;
}
```

```
char key[512];
int index = 0;
regGetValue(key, sizeof(key), index);
```

The `sizeof` operator works as expected here because it's operating on the array itself, not merely a pointer to it. This approach, however common in C APIs, is cumbersome.

You can simplify things at the call site a bit by using a function template that automatically deduces the size of your buffer and passes it to an internal helper function that actually does the work:

```
// Helper function, implemented as a private member of your class
DWORD regGetValue(char *key, size_t length int index)
{
   HKEY hKey; 
   RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM",0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&hKey);
   DWORD chars = length;
   LONG result = RegEnumValue(hKey, index, key, &chars, 0,0,0,0 );
   RegCloseKey(hKey);
   return result;
}

// The public function that you will actually call
template <size_t N>
DWORD regGetValue(char (&key)[N], int index)
{
   return regGetValue(key, N, index);
}
```

```
char key[512];
int index = 0;
regGetValue(key, index);  // length determined and passed automatically
```

This works because you pass *a reference* to the array, rather than a pointer.

Aside from all of that, I have to seriously question why you're calling ANSI functions and using `char*` for your strings. All modern Windows applications should be Unicode. That means calling the `W`-suffixed versions of the Windows API functions and using `wchar_t*` as your string type. Make sure that both the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` symbols are defined for your project, and you'll get a compile-time error if you use the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says: If the lpName buffer is too small to receive the name of the key, the function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA. Before you call `RegEnumKeyEx`, you can call function `RegQueryInfoKey` to determine the size of the largest subkey for the key identified by `hKey`.
The usage of `RegQueryInfoKey` can find here: "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724902(v=vs.85).aspx"